# Functional equation of the alternating zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

Can one let me know about the functional equation of the alternating zeta function similar to the well known for the rieman function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since one has 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} = (1 -2^{1-s}) \zeta (s)$$ 
you get a Functional equation directly from the one for $\zeta$.

Note: This is function is also called [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) ; the linked Wikipedia page also has the equation spelled out.